# How to start capturing data from a specific row(say A8) value using Userform

Tags: vba, excel

[Desired Output should start from A8 row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Im6FC.jpg)I want to start capturing the data from a particular row range say `A8` and continuing to next rows. In my code I am getting an error in selecting the range can anyone guide me to solve this error.

Below is the attached code:

```
Private Sub cmdadd_Click()
    Dim StockNumber As Long, LastRow As Long
    Dim wsStockSheet As Worksheet
    Set wsStockSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    StockNumber = Application.Max(wsStockSheet.Columns(1)) + 1

    With wsStockSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            .Range("A8").Select
            .Range("A" & LastRow).Value = StockNumber
            .Range("B" & LastRow).Value = Me.cbodd.Text
            .Range("C" & LastRow).Value = Me.txtPro.Text
            .Range("D" & LastRow).Value = Me.txtEn.Text
        End With    
 End Sub
```

Comment: `For i=8 to LastRow` after `LastRow=...`,  `.Range("A" & i)`, and `Next` before `End With`. But your code seems to be writing the text of the form controls repeatedly in every row. Is that what you really want?

Comment: You should be using `.Range("A8:A" & LastRow)`. Also your code is not getting data from that range it is placing data from `StockNumber 'into that range. You also need a loop.

Comment: After looking at this, i think you want to copy the data in the textboxes to the first empty row in columns A through D. Is that correct?

Comment: See my edit to the answer

Comment: `I want to tranfer the userform data to first empty row in column A but my first empty row starts from A8.`: then your original code is doing the job. Just delete `.Range("A8").Select`

Comment: `but my first empty row starts from A8`: are you trying to say that, if there are not cells with data, you want to start in A8? If this is the case, in your code you can add, after the definition of `LastRow`, the following line: `If (LastRow < 8) Then LastRow = 8`

Comment: If there is data in cells up to A7, your code should work. If the "header" in column A is empty then my previous comment should do the trick.

Comment: @GMalc According to your code the data is capturing into A30 row not from A8 row.

Comment: @CMArg I tried with my code and your suggestions also but I am facing same problem i.e. data capturing from A30 not from A8.

Comment: @santoshpaladhi Are you sure column A has empty cells? Take into account that spaces can't be seen.... but make cells NOT EMPTY

Comment: If your image represents the starting point, then row 8 IS NOT the last one: there is data from row 22 on...! Please clarify what you're trying to accomplish: completing the empty cells from A8 to A22? Overwrite data starting in A22?

Comment: I want the maximum value in cloumn 1 to be A8.

Comment: Your code is working fine for me. Select A8 to A100 (just saying...) and press delete to get rid of spaces and the like. Or add `.Range("A8:A1000").ClearContents` after `With wsStockSheet`

Comment: Tried your suggestions now but not understanding where I am going wrong; in my excel sheet it capturing from the last row not from A8 as a first row. (I need A8 as my first row)

Comment: Excuse me, but I really can't get what you want. For example _"I want the maximum value in cloumn 1 to be A8"_ confuses me, since A8 is a range, not value. And as I said, your code is working find for me (starts writing data in A8). You can press F8 and go step by step pressing again F8. Mouse over variables will show you their values. Maybe you can spot the problem.

Comment: Thanks alot for your patience and for the solutions. I am sorry for making confusion , I am succesful after adding this line .Range("A8:A1000").ClearContents.

Comment: Good! Then there was "something" in A21 (a space maybe). Glad you solve it.

Comment: May be i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Your own code commented.

```
Private Sub cmdadd_Click() 'each time you press button cmadd
    Dim StockNumber As Long, LastRow As Long
    Dim wsStockSheet As Worksheet
    Set wsStockSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    StockNumber = Application.Max(wsStockSheet.Columns(1)) + 1 'Find the maximun value in column A. Then add one.

    With wsStockSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1 'Find last row. Then add one (i.e., the row following last with data)
        If (LastRow < 7) Then LastRow = 8 'If last row with data is less than 8, then make it be 8
            'in columns A, B, C and D of that row, write the corresponding textbox data
            .Range("A" & LastRow).Value = StockNumber
            .Range("B" & LastRow).Value = Me.cbodd.Text
            .Range("C" & LastRow).Value = Me.txtPro.Text
            .Range("D" & LastRow).Value = Me.txtEn.Text
        End With
 End Sub
```